# Geography crossword

Tags: geography, crosswords

I made a little crossword for you.

[image: Crossword]
[image: Questions]

If you get it right, the keyword will make sense for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is:

> GEOGRAPHY

1) What is the official language of the Canadian province Quebec?

> French

2) Which is the most abundant metal in the earth's crust?

> Aluminum

3) In the South, Hominy when ground is more popularly know as what?

> Grain

4) Which U.S. state has the longest coastline?

> Alaska

5) Off what country are the islands of Islay, Mull, and St. Kilda located?

> Scotland

6) What nation produces two thirds of the world’s vanilla?

> Madagascar

7) Which Nordic country was first to give women the right to vote, in 1906?

> Finland

8) Which country has the longest coastline in the world?

> Canada

9) Which city is located both in Asia and Europe?

> Istanbul

10) Mount Everest is in which mountain chain?

> Himalayan mountains

and

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3T7D.png

Comment: Wow, you’re so fast :)

Comment: Is it possible to hide the image in a spoiler?

Comment: 3 Across is Grits!

Comment: @ChrisCatignani Yes, you’re right!